# Hiding specific layer using QCheckBox widget (PyQt5/PyQGIS)

Tags: pyqgis, layers, pyqt5

I have a custom PyQGIS application that loads weather data on a basemap.  Upon selecting an analysis type, the application loads a raster layer containing a colormap and two vector layers that contain polyline (contours) and points (wind barbs).  The result looks like this:

[image]

On the "overlay" window a QAction is set to pop open a QDialog window that lists the three layers added with checkboxes.  Checking or unchecking the box is supposed to show or hide the associated layer, respectively.  Here is an excerpt of my code (PyQGIS 3x) where the signal from the raster checkbox being changed is connected:

```
def raster_display(self):

    idx = self.overlay_choice #index of selected analysis
    bol = self.check_raster.isChecked() #saved checked state 
    self.rchk[idx] = bol #for multiple overlays so all checked states are saved
    rname = self.list_items[idx] #name of layer

    qinst = self.project.instance() # class QgsProject
    rlayer = qinst.mapLayersByName(rname)[0]
    tree = qinst.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(rlayer.id())

    if tree:
        tree.setItemVisibilityChecked(bol)
    else:
        print("Layer tree not valid")

    self.QMC.refresh() #class QgsMapCanvas
```

While the checkbox does connect to the signal correctly (printing the checked state reveals the correct boolean and the 'layer tree not valid' is not printed), none of the layers change to being hidden.

Comment: Did you use `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` to sync your canvas with your `layerTreeRoot` e.g demo in section "Interaction with Canvas" https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/? Otherwise your event triggered by `setItemVisibilityChecked` method will never "propagate" to the canvas

Comment: @ThomasG77 I did not, and that seems to be the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @ThomasG77, you need to:

> … use `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` to sync your canvas with your
> `layerTreeRoot` e.g demo in section "Interaction with Canvas"
> https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/?
> Otherwise your event triggered by `setItemVisibilityChecked` method
> will never "propagate" to the canvas